# How to put quotation marks above and below letters d and p

Tags: symbols, letters

I want to put quotation marks (and apostrophe) above and bellow letters `p` and `d`. This is what i want:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia0AA.jpg)

As you can see, the crossed letters are the correct ones, so it would be amazing if there is a way to label it, either with a crossed line (like in the image) or with a number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of the [cancel package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cancel?lang=en)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. I suggest you start by reading about the `\overset` and `\underset` commands, as well as the `cancel` package.

Comment: I can see a small image with 14 lines and many things on each line, but i have absolutely no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: those aren't really "quotation marks".  they are combining diacritics, unicode 030D, 030E, 0329 and 0348.  and they are placed at a uniform height or depth regardless of the shape of the embellished letter or presence of cancellation.  they don't all seem to be supported by `tipa`; i'm looking for other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach could meet your expectations

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\myoverset}[2]{%
  \mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.1ex{%
  \kern -0.6ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\vss}}}

\newcommand{\myunderset}[2]{%
  \mathop{#2}\limits_{\vbox to -.1ex{%
  \kern -1.2ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\vss}}}

\newcommand\can[1]{\kern0.1em\centernot{#1}\kern0.1em}  % Cancel command
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\myoverset{#2}{\myunderset{#3}{\text{#1}}}} % Main environment (acc:=accent command)
\newcommand{\sq}{\text{\text\textquotesingle}} % sq:=single quote
\newcommand{\dq}{\text{\text\textquotedbl}}  % dq:=double quote

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Normal versions}

\[
\acc{p}{\sq}{}
\acc{p}{\dq}{}
\acc{p}{}{\sq}
\acc{p}{}{\dq}
\acc{d}{\sq}{}
\acc{d}{\dq}{}
\acc{d}{}{\sq}
\acc{d}{}{\dq}
\]

\[
\acc{p}{\sq}{\sq}
\acc{p}{\dq}{\sq}
\acc{p}{\sq}{\dq}
\acc{p}{\dq}{\dq}
\acc{d}{\sq}{\sq}
\acc{d}{\dq}{\sq}
\acc{d}{\sq}{\dq}
\acc{d}{\dq}{\dq}
\]

\textbf{Cancelled versions}

\[
\can{\acc{p}{\sq}{}}
\can{\acc{p}{\dq}{}}
\can{\acc{p}{}{\sq}}
\can{\acc{p}{}{\dq}}
\can{\acc{d}{\sq}{}}
\can{\acc{d}{\dq}{}}
\can{\acc{d}{}{\sq}}
\can{\acc{d}{}{\dq}}
\]

\[
\can{\acc{p}{\sq}{\sq}}
\can{\acc{p}{\dq}{\sq}}
\can{\acc{p}{\sq}{\dq}}
\can{\acc{p}{\dq}{\dq}}
\can{\acc{d}{\sq}{\sq}}
\can{\acc{d}{\dq}{\sq}}
\can{\acc{d}{\sq}{\dq}}
\can{\acc{d}{\dq}{\dq}}
\]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I considered @Mico's suggestions and changed the commands `\overset`and `\underset` to `\myoverset`and `\myunderset`, respectively. Also edited instruction `\texttt{}` inside definition of the main new environment.

Comment: I don't think you need to "wrap" `\texttt` inside `\text`. `\texttt{...}` should suffice. A separate thought: Repurposing the macro names `\overset` and `\underset` may cause problems in a document in which the "original" forms of the macros are used.

Comment: @Cragfelt Thank you so much! It was really helpful.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your suggestions. I have made some changes in my code according to them. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JuanDuarte You are welcome. I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Or with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % access \textquotedbl
\usepackage{textcomp}     % access \textquotesingle
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength{\dheight}
\newlength{\pdepth}
\newcommand{\abo}[2]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{8pt}{#1}{\mbox{\vline height \dheight depth \pdepth width 0pt #2}}}
\newcommand{\bel}[2]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-10pt}{#1}{\mbox{\vline height 10pt depth \pdepth width 0pt #2}}}

\begin{document}
    Normal text:    
    \settowidth{\dheight}{\heightof{d}}
    \settowidth{\pdepth}{\depthof{p}}
    \abo{'}{d}
    \abo{\textquotedblright}{d}
    \abo{'}{p}
    \abo{\textquotedblright}{p}
    \bel{'}{d}
    \bel{\textquotedblright}{d}
    \bel{'}{p}
    \bel{\textquotedblright}{p}
    \cancel{\abo{'}{d}}
    \cancel{\abo{\textquotedblright}{d}}
    \cancel{\abo{'}{p}}
    \cancel{\abo{\textquotedblright}{p}}
    \cancel{\bel{'}{d}}
    \cancel{\bel{\textquotedblright}{d}}
    \cancel{\bel{'}{p}}
    \cancel{\bel{\textquotedblright}{p}}    

    \ttfamily
    ttfamily:
    \settowidth{\dheight}{\heightof{d}}
    \settowidth{\pdepth}{\depthof{p}}
    \abo{\textquotesingle}{d}
    \abo{"}{d}
    \abo{\textquotesingle}{p}
    \abo{"}{p}
    \bel{\textquotesingle}{d}
    \bel{"}{d}
    \bel{\textquotesingle}{p}
    \bel{"}{p}
    \cancel{\abo{\textquotesingle}{d}}
    \cancel{\abo{"}{d}}
    \cancel{\abo{\textquotesingle}{p}}
    \cancel{\abo{"}{p}}
    \cancel{\bel{\textquotesingle}{d}}
    \cancel{\bel{"}{d}}
    \cancel{\bel{\textquotesingle}{p}}
    \cancel{\bel{"}{p}} 

    \sffamily
    sffamily:
    \settowidth{\dheight}{\heightof{d}}
    \settowidth{\pdepth}{\depthof{p}}
    \abo{'}{d}
    \abo{"}{d}
    \abo{'}{p}
    \abo{"}{p}
    \bel{'}{d}
    \bel{"}{d}
    \bel{'}{p}
    \bel{"}{p}
    \cancel{\abo{'}{d}}
    \cancel{\abo{"}{d}}
    \cancel{\abo{'}{p}}
    \cancel{\abo{"}{p}}
    \cancel{\bel{'}{d}}
    \cancel{\bel{"}{d}}
    \cancel{\bel{'}{p}}
    \cancel{\bel{"}{p}} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JuanDuarte You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (The screeshot you posted isn't exactly easy to decipher...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % access \textquotedbl
\usepackage{textcomp}     % access \textquotesingle
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for "\text" macro
\usepackage{accents}      % for "\accentset" and "\underaccent" macros

\def\dsquoteup{$\accentset{\text{\textquotesingle}}{\text{d}}$}
\def\ddquoteup{$\accentset{\text{\textquotedbl}}{\text{d}}$}
\def\psquoteup{$\accentset{\text{\textquotesingle}}{\text{p}}$}
\def\pdquoteup{$\accentset{\text{\textquotedbl}}{\text{p}}$}
\def\dsquotedn{$\underaccent{\text{\textquotesingle}}{\text{d}}$}
\def\ddquotedn{$\underaccent{\text{\textquotedbl}}{\text{d}}$}
\def\psquotedn{$\underaccent{\text{\textquotesingle}}{\text{p}}$}
\def\pdquotedn{$\underaccent{\text{\textquotedbl}}{\text{p}}$}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\dsquoteup\ddquoteup\psquoteup\pdquoteup \dsquotedn\ddquotedn\psquotedn\pdquotedn

\sffamily
\dsquoteup\ddquoteup\psquoteup\pdquoteup \dsquotedn\ddquotedn\psquotedn\pdquotedn
\end{document}
```